# Can we have a virtual static method ? (c++)

Tags: c++, static, virtual

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C++ static virtual members?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1820477/c-static-virtual-members)

Can we have a virtual static method (in C++) ? I've tried to compile the following 
code :

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A
{
public:
    virtual static void f() {cout << "A's static method" << endl;}
};

class B :public A
{
public:
    static void f() {cout << "B's static method" << endl;}
};

int main()
{
    /* some code */
    return 0;
}
```

but the compiler says that :

```
member 'f' cannot be declared both virtual and static
```

so I guess the answer is no , but why ?

thanks ,
Ron

Comment: There is no real reason. It is just not supported in C++. (It works in Python: https://ideone.com/fWtTUi) - You can create a virtual wrapper around a static method: A virtual method that ignores the object and forwards the call to the static method.

Answer (score 60):

No. `static` on a function in a class means that the function doesn't need an object to operate on. `virtual` means the implementation depends on the type of the calling object. For static there is no calling object, so it doesn't make sense to have both `static` and `virtual` on the same function
.

Comment: Your answer is correct, but your explanation is not. You could use an object to determine which static method to call. In Python it works like that: https://ideone.com/fWtTUi

Comment: @not-a-user You can also call a static function from an object in C++, so  you can do `f.static_function()` as well as 'F::static_function()` (I said doesn't need an object, not cant be called on). 

But you're right - in the case where we have an object C++ could use the vtable to look up an appropriate function - in which case virtual static would make sense. 

And as you say overloading could be used to forward a virtual call to the correct static function (or does the compiler consider that ambiguous?)

Answer (score 3):

Don't think this is possible because you could call `A::F();` without having the object A.
Making it virtual and static would mean a contradiction.

Comment: Aha , then static means that *this doesn't exists , virtual means that the method has a this pointer . The combining of the two makes a contradiction . Nice :) thanks

Comment: No, there is no contradiction. In `A::F()` the class is hardcoded, while in `this->F()` the right function to call could be derived from the object (via virtual function lookup). The fact is that C++ has no support for this. In Python it works out of the box: https://ideone.com/fWtTUi

Answer (score 2):

No, `static` function is like global function, but also inside class namespace. `virtual` implies inheritance and reimplementing in derived class - you can't reimplement 'global' function.

Answer (score 1):

Because the class doesn't have a `this` pointer. In there is the virtual function lookup table. A quick google can tell you more about the virtual function lookup table.