# A C++ idiom for per-class data, accessible without needing virtual getter methods

Tags: c++, design-patterns, static-members, idioms, multiton

(This question is related to reflection, but isn't really about reflection)

I have this hierarchy of classes (say `class A` and `class B : public A`), and in addition to instance-specific data, I'd like to have class-specific data shared by all instances. For example, suppose I want to have a `FunnyClassName` string for each of my classes.

I would like to be able to have *non-virtual* getters for my per-class data, such as:

```
/*can it be static? */ const std::string& A::GetFunnyName();
```

and the most important thing is that I want to have no, or as little as possible, boilerplate code in inheriting classes. The getters are to be implemented once in `class A` (the root of the class hierarchy); class B should specify its FunnyClassName some other way.

It's been suggested (e.g. indirectly in questions here on SO) that a Multiton object, using the class' type hash as a key, might be the basis of a reasonable solution. Is that the case? Is there 'standard' code which does this (e.g. in the STL or in Boost)? Is there another relevant approach?

**Notes**:

- Think this is impossible? See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1820477/1593077) and [this (laconic) answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1820544/1593077). But as some commenters and responders suggest, it may be necessary to have non-static getters, and make the weaker constraint of not having to rewrite the getter for every class (i.e. using RTTI).
- If C++ had static virtual data members, this would be trivial - `virtual static const std::string FunnyName`. With static virtual methods it would also be possible but only if we drop our demand for the getter only being implemented in the base class. We would have something like `/* static??*/ static const std::string& A::GetFunnyName() { return "Aye"; }` and `/* static??*/ const std::string& B::GetFunnyName() { return "Bee"; }`.
- I'm not particularly interested in the case of templated classes, but if you want to address that as well, that's nice.
- FunnyName() is just an example. It could be `const Thing& GetFunnyThing()`. I don't want anything like the class' name from typeid.name(), or its demangling, or such.
- C++11 is ok, but a solution in C++03 would be better. No C++14 please.

Comment: I don't understand the problem here. What's wrong with the code you posted? Could you show us the expected behaviour?

Comment: How are you supposed to invoke those "class" functions? Are they supposed to be registered at runtime or it is a compile-time feature?

Comment: @KarolyHorvath What code he posted? I don't understand what is being asked.

Comment: Why can't you just use static member functions?

Comment: @BЈовић: code. you know, stuff that isn't plain english text.

Comment: @Simple: The getters for class-specific data should be static, yes. Corrected.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath: The problem is that a static method of the base class needs to have different behavior based on what the calling instance' actual class is.

Comment: @Simple `static` member functions cannot be `virtual`.

Comment: @GermánDiago: The getter functions should exist at compile-time.

Comment: @einpoklum: Static methods are basically free functions with access control. There is no calling instance for a static method.

Comment: @einpoklum Does `typeid(*this).name()` do what you want? I guess not, so please explain in your question why it doesn't.

Comment: @Walter: You're right, see edit.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to enforce a static member on derived classes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10502114/how-to-enforce-a-static-member-on-derived-classes)

Comment: @Walter obviously, but the question states the OP wants non-virtual getters. So...

Comment: @anatolyg: IIANM, if we have `A* a1 = new B()`, wouldn't `typeid(*A).name()` give me the value for A rather than B?

Comment: Why [the following simple solution](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6e388ce33c1733ee) doesn't satisfy your conditions?

Comment: @Constructor: [Here's why](http://ideone.com/yhzdYO)...

Comment: @einpoklum So you want polymorphic solution working at run-time without virtual functions, don't you?

Comment: @Constructor: No, I didn't say you can't use virtual functions. The getters need to be static, that's all.

Comment: @einpoklum Why do you want them to be static?

Comment: @Constructor: You know what? If they're not static, but do not use any data members of the instance (i.e. they only use the vtable), then maybe I can tolerate that. If you have something in mind.

Comment: @einpoklum Of course [I have](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cf7091890db8a5bf). What conditions are violated here?

Comment: @Constructor: In your sample code, you're not accessing a and b via `A*`s.

Comment: @einpoklum What? Both `a` and `b` are `A*`!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59651/discussion-between-einpoklum-and-constructor).

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to use `virtual`, you can use templates. The name of this idiom is **[Curiously recurring template pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern)**, and it's used in ATL and WTL.

Look code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

template <typename C>
class Super
{
public:
    std::string GetFunnyName() const
    {
        C *thiz = static_cast<C *>(this);
        return thiz->GetFunnyName();
    }
};
class A : public Super<A>
{
public:
    std::string GetFunnyName() const
    {
        return "A";
    }
};
class B : public Super<B>
{
public:
    std::string GetFunnyName() const
    {
        return "B";
    }
};

template <typename TSuper>
void OutputFunny(const TSuper &obj)
{
    std::cout << obj.GetFunnyName() << "\n";
}

int main()
{
    A a;
    B b;

    OutputFunny(a);
    OutputFunny(b);
}
```

[(live example)](http://ideone.com/5DpqLE)

If you want to make `B` inherit `A`, code like this:

```
template <typename C>
class A_base : public Super<C>
{
    ...
};
class A : public A_base<A> { };

class B : public A_base<B>
{
    ...
};
```

[(live example)](http://ideone.com/LdAqMa)

My example code uses **compile-time polymorphism**. So, it cannot be applied in runtime. If you want to get "FunnyName" in runtime, you should use `virtual`, *run-time polymorphism*.

---

Curiously recurring template pattern works like this:

You may see the basic form of the pattern.

```
template <typename C>
class Super
{
    void foo()
    {
        C *thiz = static_cast<C *>(this);
        thiz->foo();
    }
    ...
};

class Derived : public Super<Derived>
{
    void foo()
    {
        std::cout << "fooo!!\n";
    }
    ...
};
```

The derived class inherit `Super`, with `Derived` itself as template parameter.

`Super<Derived>` is concretized like this:

```
template <>
class Super<Derived>
{
    void foo()
    {
        Derived *thiz = static_cast<Derived *>(this); // 1
        thiz->foo();                                  // 2
    }
};
```

On `1`, we're casting `this` pointer into `Derived *`, and call `foo` with this casted pointer on `2`. Since the type of pointer is `Derived *`, `thiz->foo();` statement will call `Derived::foo`.

([wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) explanation seems good)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59646/discussion-between-einpoklum-and-ikh).

Comment: Ah. Ok, well, the thing is, B does still not inherit A... they don't even have a common ancestor now.

Comment: @einpoklum They have common ancestor, `A_base<>` (and also `A_base<>` inherits `Super<>`, of course). In my code, `class A` is just trick-class to use `A` directly, and it's `A_base<>` that is the *real* `A`.

Comment: @einpoklum Well, in fact, it's *not* real ancestor because it's class template, but that's ok when using the compile-time polymorphism; If you need run-time polymorphism, it may occur some problems.

Comment: Well, like I said - B inherits A, that's not going to go away. I need to pass `B*`s as `A*`s... that's the whole point of the exercise.

Comment: @einpoklum Then you cannot use compile-time polymorphism; Since you begin to store the pointer of `B` into `A *` variables, we cannot know the *real* type of objects and need run-time overhead to figure what the real type of an object is. In use of compile-time polymorphism, we perform polymorphism-task by template, not pointer of base class.

Answer (score 2):

Your (original) question is ill-posed (or can be answered by **this is impossible**). One the one hand you want *The getters are to be implemented once in class A (the root of the class hierarchy) and that's that*. On the other hand you suggest that *If C++ had static virtual data members, this would be trivial*. However, with `static virtual` methods you still would need to re-implement the getters for each derived class, contradicting your first request.

I have implemented some code with the same aim, i.e. giving a nice name description for each class.

```
namespace some_namespace {
  /// demangles symbol name as returned by typeid(T).name()
  std::string demangle(const char*mangled_name);
  inline std::string demangle(std::string const&mangled_name)
  { return demangle(mangled_name.c_str()); }

  /// provides the name for any type
  template<typename T>
  struct name_traits
  {
  private:
    template<typename U, U> struct check;
    template<typename U>
    static std::true_type test(check<std::string(*)(), &U::name_of_type>*);
    template<typename U>
    static std::false_type test(...);
    //  NOTE what_type required to trick icpc 14.0.2 to compile
    typedef decltype(test<T>(0)) what_type;
    /// true if static std::string T::name_of_type()  exists
    static constexpr bool has_name_of_type = what_type::value;
    /// return name of types with static std::string name_of_type()
    template<bool S>
    static enable_if_t< S, std::string>
    name_t() { return T::name_of_type(); }
    /// return name of all other types: demangle typeid(T).name();
    template<bool S>
    static enable_if_t<!S, std::string>
    name_t()
    { return demangle(typeid(T).name()); }
  public:
    static std::string name()
    { return name_t<has_name_of_type>(); }
  };
}
/// macro  returning the name of a given type.
#define nameof(TYPE) some_namespace::name_traits<TYPE>::name()
```

Here, any type `A` may be equipped with `std::string A::name_of_type();` to provide the info, or a specialisation `struct some_namespace::name_traits<A>` may given. If neither is the case, the name is picked up from demangling the `typeid`.

Comment: @einpoklum yes, but not dynamically: If `B` **is a** `A`, this should work: `A* a=new B();`, what do you intend `a.getFunnyName()` should do?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59638/discussion-between-wolf-and-einpoklum).

Comment: I see I should have used const `Thing& GetFunnyThing()` so as not to make it seem I was interested in names... anyway, I take it `A` should inherit `name_traits<A>` ?

Comment: No, `A` must not inherit `name_traits<A>`.

Comment: @Walter: Edited my question to be less-ill-posed.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure this answers the question, but you should consider using [`typeid`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typeid). This is a part of RTTI, so it can distinguish static and dynamic types.

Have the following code in your base class:

```
struct A {
    ...
    std::string GetFunnyName() {return typeid(*this).name();}
};
```

The strings returned for different derived classes will be different; however, you don't have any control on what these strings will look like (they may contain e.g. a mangled version of the type name).

You may want to use a `std::map` to translate these system-generated names into more preferred ones like `FunnyName1`, `FunnyName2` etc, but you cannot extract the name of the derived class (or maybe you can, but not in a portable way).

[Here](http://ideone.com/Pt5H3K) is a demo.

---

Edit: since you really want to work with `FunnyThing` and not with `FunnyName`, you should definitely use a `map`. Make it a static object:

```
struct A {
private:
    static std::map<std::string, Thing*> my_map;
    ...
}
```

Then use it to convert `string` to `Thing`:

```
struct A {
    ...
public:
    Thing& GetFunnyThing() {return *my_map[typeid(*this).name()];}
    ...
};
```

Now each derived class should use `RegisterThing` to "declare" which `Thing` it wants to return.

```
struct A {
    ...
protected:
    static void RegisterThing(std::string name, Thing* thing) {my_map[name] = thing;}
    ...
}
```

Calling this method only once, and at the correct time, can be implemented in different ways (like the Singleton pattern can be), so I don't want to complicate matters by giving an example.

Comment: I guess maybe I do need RTTI... which make the static restriction on the getter too strict. See my edit about using `typeid().name()`