# How to simplify a function referencing itself as argument ? (and what does this mean)

Tags: assembly, x86-64, reverse-engineering, disassembly, ida

I encounter often a function calling itself (in the pseudo code, produced by IDA) such as:

```
result = (**(__int64 (__fastcall ***)(volatile signed __int32 *))lambda)(lambda);
```

1. Since the disassembly is `call qword ptr [rax]`, can't this be simplified into `result = lambda();` if I translate the pseudo code in c ?
2. Why in the pseudo code the function is having itself as argument ?
3. What is happening when there is a call such as `lambda + 8i64` (ie., `call qword ptr [rax+8]`) ?

Here a more complete context:

```
__int64 __fastcall CR_maybeParseWithLambda(_QWORD *a1, __int64 newPtr, __int64 positionOrCounter)
{
  volatile signed __int32 *lambda; // rdi
  __int64 result; // rax

  lambda = (volatile signed __int32 *)a1[1];
  if ( lambda )
  {
    result = (unsigned int)_InterlockedExchangeAdd(lambda + 2, 0xFFFFFFFF);
    if ( (_DWORD)result == 1 )
    {
      result = (**(__int64 (__fastcall ***)(volatile signed __int32 *))lambda)(lambda);
      if ( _InterlockedExchangeAdd(lambda + 3, 0xFFFFFFFF) == 1 )
        result = (*(__int64 (__fastcall **)(volatile signed __int32 *))(*(_QWORD *)lambda + 8i64))(lambda);
      a1[1] = positionOrCounter;
      *a1 = newPtr;
    }
    else
    {
      a1[1] = positionOrCounter;
      *a1 = newPtr;
    }
  }
  else
  {
    a1[1] = positionOrCounter;
    *a1 = newPtr;
  }
  return result;
}
```

The disassembly, also from IDA:

```
.text:0000000180005F70 ; __int64 __fastcall CR_maybeParseWithLambda(_QWORD *a1, __int64 newPtr, __int64 positionOrCounter)
.text:0000000180005F70 CR_maybeParseWithLambda proc near       ; CODE XREF: sub_180005B10+10F↑p
.text:0000000180005F70                                         ; sub_180005B10+14A↑p ...
.text:0000000180005F70
.text:0000000180005F70 arg_0           = qword ptr  8
.text:0000000180005F70 arg_8           = qword ptr  10h
.text:0000000180005F70 arg_10          = qword ptr  18h
.text:0000000180005F70 arg_18          = qword ptr  20h
.text:0000000180005F70
.text:0000000180005F70                 mov     [rsp+arg_8], rbx
.text:0000000180005F75                 mov     [rsp+arg_10], rbp
.text:0000000180005F7A                 mov     [rsp+arg_18], rsi
.text:0000000180005F7F                 push    rdi
.text:0000000180005F80                 sub     rsp, 20h
.text:0000000180005F84                 mov     rdi, [rcx+8]
.text:0000000180005F88                 mov     rsi, r8
.text:0000000180005F8B                 mov     rbp, rdx
.text:0000000180005F8E                 mov     rbx, rcx
.text:0000000180005F91                 test    rdi, rdi
.text:0000000180005F94                 jz      short loc_180005FF3
.text:0000000180005F96
.text:0000000180005F96 loc_180005F96:                          ; DATA XREF: .rdata:0000000180401E74↓o
.text:0000000180005F96                                         ; .rdata:0000000180401E84↓o ...
.text:0000000180005F96                 mov     [rsp+28h+arg_0], r14
.text:0000000180005F9B                 or      r14d, 0FFFFFFFFh
.text:0000000180005F9F                 mov     eax, r14d
.text:0000000180005FA2                 lock xadd [rdi+8], eax
.text:0000000180005FA7                 cmp     eax, 1
.text:0000000180005FAA                 jnz     short loc_180005FEA
.text:0000000180005FAC                 mov     rax, [rdi]
.text:0000000180005FAF                 mov     rcx, rdi
.text:0000000180005FB2                 call    qword ptr [rax]
.text:0000000180005FB4                 lock xadd [rdi+0Ch], r14d
.text:0000000180005FBA                 cmp     r14d, 1
.text:0000000180005FBE                 jnz     short loc_180005FC9
.text:0000000180005FC0                 mov     rax, [rdi]
.text:0000000180005FC3                 mov     rcx, rdi
.text:0000000180005FC6                 call    qword ptr [rax+8]
.text:0000000180005FC9
.text:0000000180005FC9 loc_180005FC9:                          ; CODE XREF: CR_maybeParseWithLambda+4E↑j
.text:0000000180005FC9                 mov     [rbx+8], rsi
.text:0000000180005FCD                 mov     [rbx], rbp
.text:0000000180005FD0
.text:0000000180005FD0 loc_180005FD0:                          ; CODE XREF: CR_maybeParseWithLambda+81↓j
.text:0000000180005FD0                 mov     r14, [rsp+28h+arg_0]
.text:0000000180005FD5
.text:0000000180005FD5 loc_180005FD5:                          ; CODE XREF: CR_maybeParseWithLambda+8A↓j
.text:0000000180005FD5                                         ; DATA XREF: .pdata:0000000180483888↓o ...
.text:0000000180005FD5                 mov     rbx, [rsp+28h+arg_8]
.text:0000000180005FDA                 mov     rbp, [rsp+28h+arg_10]
.text:0000000180005FDF                 mov     rsi, [rsp+28h+arg_18]
.text:0000000180005FE4                 add     rsp, 20h
.text:0000000180005FE8                 pop     rdi
.text:0000000180005FE9                 retn
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 1. Since the disassembly is `call qword ptr [rax]`, can't this be simplified into `result = lambda();` if I translate the pseudo code in c ?

No. The decompiler detect that the variable passed in is likely an argument of the called function.

For example, `void f()` and `void f(int)` functions are both called with a single `call` assembly command, except that in the latter case, the caller moves an `int` value to an appropriate register before calling the function.

You can change the type of `lambda` to avoid that.

> 2. Why in the pseudo code the function is having itself as argument ?

Read both the assembly code and the decompiled code **very** carefully. `lambda` is not a function pointer, to get a function pointer from it it's necessary to dereference **twice**. So it could be something like this (pseudo-C++ code)

```c
using FunctionType=int(int);
struct B{
    FunctionType* functionPointer;
};
struct A{
    B* b;
};
A* lambda; // the variable name is a little misleading, given this interpretation.
auto functionPointer=(*(*lambda).b);
functionPointer(lambda);
```

Given the double-dereference, it's very likely that `B` is actually a [vftable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6664313/vftable-what-is-this) (although in these cases, the function are usually called with `__thiscall` convention) -- so the code could be written like this:

```c
struct Base{
    virtual void someFunction(){}
    virtual void otherFunction(){}
};
struct Base_vftableType{ // compiler-generated
    void (*someFunction)(Base*); // explicit (this) argument shown
    void (*otherFunction)(Base*); // explicit (this) argument shown
};
struct Derived: Base{
    Base_vftableType *vftable; // compiler-generated
    void someFunction(){ /* ... */ }
};
Base_vftableType derived_vftable{ /* ... */ }; // compiler-generated vftable

Derived *a;

// the function call is something like this in pseudo-C
// (and probably how it will be displayed in IDA):
a->vftable->someFunction(a);
```

> 3. What is happening when there is a call such as `lambda + 8i64` (ie., `call qword ptr [rax+8]`) ?

Similarly, there could be more than one functions in the vftable, and the `+` simply takes the address of other functions.

Assuming 64-bit function pointers, `+8` would be the second function in the table.

See also: [c++ - How to organize vtables in IDA Pro? - Reverse Engineering Stack Exchange](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/11811/how-to-organize-vtables-in-ida-pro/16651)

Comment: More see-also: possible-duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11000067/is-there-any-way-to-restore-struct-by-reverse-engineering-pointer-to-that-struc