# init static variables of derived classes in parent class method

Tags: c++, c++17, static-members

I am trying to reduce code duplication in an init function that initializes static members of derived classes. In my case, this function is called `initTypeInfo`. Originally, each of my child classes `ChildA`, `ChildB` ... `ChildN` had their own `initTypeInfo`. Once I decided to move `initTypeInfo` into the `Parent` class because pretty much all the code except the namespace of the static member (`ChildA::s_typeInfo` vs. `ChildB::s_typeInfo` ...) was the same, I started to see problems with the static member `s_typeInfo`. This variable is a smart pointer of type `std::shared_ptr<TypeInfo>`

Here is my code sample:

```
#include <string>
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

struct TypeInfo
{
    std::string name;
    // other members ...
};

class Parent 
{
    public:
    Parent(std::string name)
    : m_name(name)
    {

    }

    virtual std::shared_ptr<TypeInfo> getTypeInfo() = 0;

    virtual void initTypeInfo()
    {
        // this function contains lots of common code, trying to avoid code duplication 

        std::shared_ptr<TypeInfo> typeInfo = getTypeInfo();

        // initialize if it hasn't already been initialized 
        if (typeInfo == nullptr)
        {
            TypeInfo info {m_name};
            // the variable Child<n>::s_typeInfo doesn't point to this allocated data :(
            typeInfo = std::make_shared<TypeInfo>(info);
        }
    }

    private:
    std::string m_name;
};

class ChildA : public Parent
{
    public:
    ChildA(std::string name  /*other params...*/)
    : Parent(name)
    {
        initTypeInfo();
    }

    std::shared_ptr<TypeInfo> getTypeInfo()
    {
        return s_typeInfo;
    }

    private:    
    inline static std::shared_ptr<TypeInfo> s_typeInfo = nullptr;
    // other members...
};


class ChildB : public Parent
{
    public:
    ChildB(std::string name  /*other params...*/)
    : Parent(name)
    {
        initTypeInfo();
    }

    std::shared_ptr<TypeInfo>  getTypeInfo()
    {
        return s_typeInfo;
    }

    private:    
    inline static std::shared_ptr<TypeInfo> s_typeInfo = nullptr;
    // other members...
};


int main()
{
    ChildA ca1("childa1");
    ChildA ca2("childa2");

    ChildB cb1("Childb1");

    return 1;
}
```

So my questions are:

1. Is this bad design to begin with, where I initialize the static member in the parent class
2. How can the code duplication here be addressed?
3. I know returning by value is the preferred way to return smart pointers from a function. But in this case, how can I have my member `Child<n>::s_typeInfo` point to the data I allocated in `Parent::initTypeInfo()`

The links I followed online pointed me to [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28524588/3021102) so I suppose I could achieve this with templates, but I'm not convinced that's the only way to do this.

Edit1:

In practice `TypeInfo` doesn't only contain one data member. It's a complex class with several data members and methods. Initially I had `initTypeInfo` functions in each derived class which would initialize each `s_typeInfo`. However, turns out that the logic in all these `initTypeInfo` functions were the same! The only difference was that the specific `s_typeInfo` of each derived class had to be initialized. So I wanted a way to transfer the logic into the `Parent` class (thereby reducing duplication) but also init the static `s_typeNode` in the parent. I guess, alternatively the question could be, how do I get the child class `shared_ptr` to point to the `TypeInfo` I create in `Parent::initTypeInfo()`?

The reason `s_typeInfo` exists as a static member is because I want to share that class across all instances of a certain Child. So in my main if for example I start 4 instance of `ChildA` I need them to share a single `ChildA::s_typeInfo` and if I have 10 instances of `ChildB`, I need them to share a single `ChildB::s_typeInfo`.

Edit2:

Adding minimal example of code for what I want to achieve. I was expecting `*(c.p)` to be 1 instead of `nullptr` as I had returned from `C::get()` by reference.

```
class C
{
    public:
    std::shared_ptr<int> & get() 
    {
        return p;
    }
    inline static std::shared_ptr<int> p = nullptr;
};

int main()
{
    C c;

    std::shared_ptr<int> p1 = c.get();

    if (p1 == nullptr)
    {
        p1 = std::make_shared<int>(1);
    }
    
    std::cout << *p1 << std::endl;

    if (c.p == nullptr)
    {
        std::cout << "nullptr" << std::endl;
    }
    else 
    {
        std::cout << *(c.p) << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why not initialize it in constructor then?

Comment: The base class should handle base class initialization and derived classes should handle their own initialization.

Comment: You might want to look up CRTP pattern

Comment: The shown logic seems to be flawed. I am unable to find anything that actually initializes `childA::s_typeInfo` and `childB::s_typeInfo`. There are functions that return their values. But absolutely nothing that actually initializes them.

Comment: It is quite horrendous. Initializing static members from constructors in **never** a great idea, and usually ends up in flames. From the snippet it is not clear why any of this is needed. What stops you from simply having a static data member in each class (TypeInfo, and not even a shared pointer!) which is statically initialized as required. Than you can have virtual getTypeInfo() returning a reference to this static member in each class supporting typeInfo. It would be a duplication, but a duplication of a single line.

Comment: *"I started to see the following problems"* -- no description of the problems are in the text following this statement. If you are going to tell us about the problems (which is a Good Idea), please do tell us about the problems.

Comment: In addition to describing the issues you faced, you might want to take a step back and present your goals and requirements. You seem to have an inkling that you might be presenting an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem), so go ahead and open the door to answers that address your original problem. Why (on an abstract level) do your classes need `TypeInfo`? Why does each class need its own `TypeInfo`? Stating *"pretty much all the code [...] was the same"* implies that some of the code differed -- what are those differences, and why are they needed?

Comment: @Retired Ninja that's how I had it at first, but that meant the `initTypeInfo` function was present in all derived classes, and the code in there was duplicated.

Comment: @Sam Varshavchik the initialization of all the `ChildN::s_typeInfo` used to be in `initTypeInfo` functions in each derived class. But the logic there was getting duplicated as it was the same for each derived class. Now the idea is that the `Parent::initTypeInfo()` will initialize `s_typeInfo`

Comment: Unfortunately, `Parent::initTypeInto()` does absolutely nothing of that sort. Can you point your finger at which line of that function that does that? That `if` statement's code does not, I repeat, initialize any child class's `s_typeinfo`. You may think it does because a ***copy*** of it ends up in it's local variable `typeinfo`, and it gets overwritten. The copy gets overwritten, not the original. C++ does not work this way.

Comment: @Sam Varshavchik I know it doesn't! That's my question #3 how can I initialize `s_typeInfo` from `Parent::initTypeInfo`?

Comment: Return it by reference, instead of value. Are you familiar with references, in C++?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik As far as I understand, I should return smart pointers by val;ue, and shouldn't that just increment the count and give me an added reference? Either way I tried returning by reference and this problem still exists -- `ClassN::s_typeInfo` is `nullptr` initially, then in `Parent::initTypeInfo` I call `ChildN::getTypeInfo` (which I tried returning by value or reference) as seen in my sample code above. Then I initialize that returned pointer by after I do that `ClassN::s_typeInfo` is still `nullptr`

Comment: I don't know what "tried returning by reference" means. I only understand actual code, and not paraphrased descriptions of it. It's true that returning by value increments the reference count of what `s_typeInfo` would point to. Except that, initially, it's not pointing to anything. It's NULL. And even if it wasn't, incrementing the reference count accomplishes absolutely nothing whatsoever, here, since `s_typeInfo` itself doesn't change. There's nothing wrong with returning anything by reference, as long as you fully understand what it means. See your C++ textbook for more info on references.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I added a sample code to my question of me returning a `shared_ptr` by reference, then initializing it. But the `C::p` in my example still is `nullptr` after that.

Comment: You're returning it by reference but then the returned reference is stored in a non-reference variable. This is no different than returning it by value. This needs to be returned by reference ***and*** stored in a reference variable. See your C++ textbook for more information on references.